# reference and populate issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[Solved - silly mistake in the model]

I have been trying to refer and populate in mongoose and expressjs, but its not working at all. I have followed these:
 1. [Mongoose examples](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/examples/population/population-basic.js)
 2. [Mongoose populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

I created **three** files:

1) models/profile.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var profileSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', profileSchema);
```

2) models/work.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var workSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    creditsFor: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'profile'}],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Work', workSchema);
```

3) controllers/work.js

```
var Work = require('../models/work.js'), fs = require('fs'), mongoose = require('mongoose');
......
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    credits = [];
    credits.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5174a9ec993af25b01000003')); // I already created a 'Profile' and copy-pasted the _id

    var work = {
    title: req.body.title,
            creditsFor: credits
    }   

    var workObj = new Work(work);

    workObj.save(function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        req.flash('info', 'Work item saved.');
        res.redirect('/work/' + data._id);
    }
    });
}
.......
exports.show = function(req, res) {
var work = req.params.work;
Work.findOne({_id: work})
    .populate('creditsFor')
    .exec(function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        res.render('site/work/show', {work: data, message: req.flash('info')});
    }
});
}
```

When using populate(), returned creditsFor is null. When I comment populate(), it is a string(?), like this:
{
title: 'My Title',
creditsFor: '5174a9ec993af25b01000003'
}

Couldn't figure out whats going wrong. I tried to bring both the models in a single file, still nothing.

Comment: You're using `'Profile'` as the model name but `'profile'` in the reference.

Comment: Sorry, 'profile' was a type while posting the question here. In the code I have 'Profile'. Still was getting the same error. But I figured out now. Made some silly mistakes in the work model. creditsFor: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile'}],
created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
updated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
creditsFor: String

So I defined creditsFor twice!

But thanks a lot! All sorted now